# Kubernetes deployment fails to perform rolling update when image tag changes

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

[Orignally raised as a [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29760), but I was asked to post it here]

I'm using GKE (Kubernetes 1.2), and most of the time everything works smoothly when performing a rolling update via a deployment config change.

Occasionally things don't.

When they don't, the deployment is correctly upgraded, but no corresponding RS is created and so the old pod (with a mismatched image to the deployment) lives on.

### Reproducing

I'm using circle ci to perform a `kubectl apply -f` with the only thing changed in the new configuration being the `image`, to make it point to a new tag.

### Broken state

#### Deployment

```
$ kubectl get deployments ployst-ui-live-deployment -o=yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "95"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: '{"kind":"Deployment","apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","metadata":{"name":"ployst-ui-live-deployment","creationTimestamp":null},"spec":{"replicas":1,"template":{"metadata":{"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"app":"ployst-ui","mode":"live"}},"spec":{"containers":[{"name":"ployst-ui","image":"eu.gcr.io/ployst-proto/ployst-ui:1.1445","ports":[{"containerPort":80}],"resources":{},"imagePullPolicy":"IfNotPresent"}],"restartPolicy":"Always","dnsPolicy":"ClusterFirst"}},"strategy":{"type":"RollingUpdate"}},"status":{}}'
  creationTimestamp: 2016-04-02T09:34:35Z
  generation: 202
  labels:
    app: ployst-ui
    mode: live
  name: ployst-ui-live-deployment
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "7467578"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/ployst-ui-live-deployment
  uid: 1c9fc5a2-f8b6-11e5-ae8f-42010af0000a
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ployst-ui
      mode: live
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: ployst-ui
        mode: live
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: eu.gcr.io/ployst-proto/ployst-ui:1.1445
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: ployst-ui
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  observedGeneration: 200
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

#### Pod

This pod should have been upgraded to

```
$ kubectl get pods ployst-ui-live-deployment-1482854615-w6hsg -o=yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/created-by: |
      {"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"ployst-ui-live-deployment-1482854615","uid":"ba2714da-5343-11e6-8d11-42010af0000a","apiVersion":"extensions","resourceVersion":"7392451"}}
    kubernetes.io/limit-ranger: 'LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container
      ployst-ui; cpu limit for container ployst-ui'
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-26T15:15:03Z
  generateName: ployst-ui-live-deployment-1482854615-
  labels:
    app: ployst-ui
    mode: live
    pod-template-hash: "1482854615"
  ...
spec:
  containers:
  - image: eu.gcr.io/ployst-proto/ployst-ui:1.1422
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: ployst-ui
    ...
```

The deployment seems fine, it's just that it seems to think it has some matching pods.

Does it not detect image change tags? If not, why does it do it sometimes?

I'm trying to find the scheduler logs - perhaps they're not available to me on GKE?

**UPDATE**

Here is the *today* output of `kubectl describe deployment ployst-ui-live-deployment` (as requested)

```
Name:           ployst-ui-live-deployment
Namespace:          default
CreationTimestamp:      Sat, 02 Apr 2016 09:34:35 +0000
Labels:         app=ployst-ui,mode=live
Selector:           app=ployst-ui,mode=live
Replicas:           1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:       RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
OldReplicaSets:     ployst-ui-live-deployment-935839453 (1/1 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:      <none>
No events.
```

The old replica set here points to a much newer one, as many deployments have happened since this issue arose.

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of `kubectl describe deployment ployst-ui-live-deployment`?

Comment: @AntoineCotten I have done so. Not sure it's going to be of much help as it's a few weeks later now...

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't help unfortunately. I was expecting to see some event or some unavailable pod.

Comment: At the time, there was nothing in the deployment that suggested anything was up. It just looked the same as above (like it thought everything was fine).

I've just upgraded to 1.3. Either the problem goes away or it will happen again in the next couple of weeks and I'll report back.

Comment: Are there other controllers (i.e. replication controller, deployments, replica sets, etc) with the selectors that overlap with the deployment's? If the controllers have overlapping selectors, they won't be able to tell which pods are created by themselves or others and would do weird things.

Comment: @janetkuo the replica sets are all unique and have been created by deployments - they seem to have a unique pod-template-hash so they're all fine. I don't have any RCs. 

All deployments are matching against a unique set of labels according to:
`$ kubectl get deployments -o=template --template="{{range .items}}
{{.metadata.name}}
{{.spec.selector.matchLabels}}
{{ end }}"

Comment: Same happened to me a couple days ago, in Kubernetes 1.3, same project as the question.

The deployment was pointing to the right image version, but a newer replicaset had not been created and the active one was pointing to an older image version. 

Killing the pod just made the replicaset spawn a newer pod of the old version. Killing the replicaset... well... that killed all pods, and the replicaset was not recreated by k8s.